# Сreate planning start endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working through mongodb database. I have a list of books and I need to do the following statistics logic. When a user reads a book, the reading time is recorded in statistics from the start of reading. I should receive the following object in json format:

```
{
  "startDate": "2020-12-31",
  "endDate": "2020-01-05",
  "books": [
    "507f1f77bcf86cd799439013"
  ]
}
```

Please help me to implement this

Comment: So, what is it you are asking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking for structure of schema this would be the best way

```
 const YourSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    startDate:Date,
    endDate:Date,
    books:[{type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'yourBook Collection'}]
 })
```